# How to send user to mobile login facebook screen?

Tags: facebook, authentication, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-authentication

I have used facebook PHP SDK which generates login Url . Which I simply put in anchor tag inside HTML . Problem is when user visiting my website on **mobile** device click on this link they see **desktop** version of facebook which I do not want .

Why facebook not checking user agent and showing there mobile website for login by default ?

Comment: could you solve the issue.. Even I am looking for the solution..

Comment: @harry yes I did check my asnwer

Comment: actually in my case.. I am trying to do this on a symbian phone.. so, button doesn't even display..!!

I could do this with the server side authentication using php sdk, by simply redirecting the user to the facbook interface..

Not the javascript sdk is able to do this, may be just because javascript doesn't work on symbian phones..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding parameter

```
display=touch
```

to the login url open up the facebook mobile site when clicked .